# Send completed PDF with PHPMailer without saving

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer

I am new to php and have been learning on the fly as I build pages.  My current task is to be able to open a PDF in browser, complete the form, and submit the form upon clicking a button at the bottom of the form.

We would like the completed form to be sent without having to save a copy to the server.  Having a two form cycle would not be horrible though.

I currently am able to send an email, but the script only sends the blank document.

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host     = "xxx.xxx.xxx"; // SMTP server

$mail->From     = "xxx@xxx.xxx";
$mail->AddAddress("xxx@xxx.xxx");

$mail->Subject  = "Attachment Test";
$mail->Body     = "Hi! \n\n This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.";
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->AddAttachment('tshirtorderform.pdf');

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
?>
```

I realize that I am telling it to retrieve the blank document, but I am coming up empty on how to attach the completed form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a semi-undocumented AddStringAttachment() method in PHPmailer, which lets you attach directly from a string, instead of requiring an actual on-disk file:

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial

search for "String Attachments". Beats me why they don't list in the Methods documentation.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, email receives an attachment with what appears to be the edited form, but Adobe gives an error when attempting to open it.

Comment: save the attachment to disk and open it with a hex editor (or even notepad). make sure it really does look like a pdf. However, note that pdf submission directly from within a pdf is a wonky thing. Adobe's taken what used to be a fairly simple "document" system and turned it into a hideous bloated mess.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended AddStringAttachment() method also, but first You need to use TCPDF to create PDF's body.

I gave some hint in this topic: [AddStringAttachment with PDF in PHPMailer not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007292/addstringattachment-with-pdf-in-phpmailer-not-work/23766227#23766227)